# Can I parse antlr4 input one prefix at a time?

Tags: antlr4

I have a file with many input pattern at a time. My grammar is as follows.

```
start
  : pattern+ EOF
  ;

pattern
  : rule1 (rule2 rule3)*
  ;
```

A pattern is a multi-line string. But the file contains many many patterns. I want to parse one pattern at a time, do some processing using the visitor, and then move to the next pattern. I want to free up most/all of the memory during previous pattern parsing. Otherwise, memory may become a problem.

What are my options with antlr. I presented the grammar in a very simple form. It will take lookahead of anything between 10 to 100 tokens to ensure that a pattern has been detected.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't actually run into performance issues yet. I suggest you run some tests with the largest of your input, and if that does not work well, post said input including your grammar here on SO for help. Right now, it's all a bit vague (we don't know what your grammar looks like, we don't have access to the patterns you mention, etc.). The question in it's current state, is not suitable for SO, IMO.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, instead of calling `parser.start()`, write a loop that calls a lexer/parser/visit, then repositions the input at the end of the loop to the position where it left off based on the tree returned from the parser. Note, you will now be calling `parser.pattern()`. To derive the new input, start at the character position `tokens.Get(tree.SourceInterval.b+1).StartIndex`. But, in this case, you may be able to probably just call `Seek()` on the next token instead.